# The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this error In WPF. On form.show()

Tags: c#, wpf, sta

Firstly I have read several answers to similar questions on the site but to be honest I find them a bit confusing (due to my lack of experience rather than the answers!). I am using a the FileSystemWatcher() class to monitor a folder for a file being created/changed. Once the event occurs I then want to load another form in the project. Instead of loading the form I get the error when the constructor on the new form is trying to execute. I am only using one thread - I'm not attempting to load the form under a different thread. My code is as follows

```
 //MainWindow
 public static void FolderWatcher()
  {
        FileSystemWatcher fsWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        fsWatcher.Path = "C:\\dump";
        fsWatcher.Filter = "*";
        fsWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
        | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        fsWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        fsWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;    
  }

  public static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
  {
       var imagePreview = new ImagePreview();
       imagePreview.Show();
  }


  //SecondForm
  public partial class ImagePreview : Window
  {
        public ImagePreview()
        {
              InitializeComponent(); //error occurs here
        }
  }
```

Hope you can help, many thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally, you should post your exception and stack trace.

Answer (score 22):

It doesn't matter how many threads you are using. There is just a rule: any thread where you are creating UI must be STA.

In case you have only one thread, this very one has to be STA. :-) In order to make the main thread an STA, you need to use the `STAThread` attribute on your `Main`:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // ...
```

If you just create a standard WPF application, the main thread is already marked with the needed attribute, so there should be no need for change.

Beware that the events from `FileSystemWatcher` may come from some other thread which is internally created by the framework. (You can check that by setting a breakpoint in `OnChanged`.) In this case, you need to *forward* the window creation to an STA thread. In case your application is a WPF application, it's done this way:

```
public static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    var d = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
    if (d.CheckAccess())
        OnChangedInMainThread();
    else
        d.BeginInvoke((Action)OnChangedInMainThread);
}

void OnChangedInMainThread()
{
    var imagePreview = new ImagePreview();
    imagePreview.Show();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Vlad, both your and Spender's solution worked. I understand why I was getting the error now.

Answer (score 5):

You're calling UI stuff from a non-UI thread (i.e. the `FileSystemWatcher` is firing the event from a non-UI thread).

I wrote an extension method that I used in my one and only WPF project (ugh):

```
public static class DispatcherEx
{
    public static void InvokeOrExecute(this Dispatcher dispatcher, Action action)
    {
        if (dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            action();
        }
        else
        {
            dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                   action);
        }
    }
}
```

so now, after making the methods non-static so you have access to the MainWindow Dispatcher, you'd do this in your event callback:

```
public void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    this.Dispatcher.InvokeOrExecute(()=>{
       var imagePreview = new ImagePreview();
       imagePreview.Show();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Spender, both your and Vlads solution worked. The explanation was also excellent - I understand why I was getting the error now.

Answer (score 1):

Use the dispatcher of the main window. Usually there is just one UI thread per application, otherwise you may get an "invalid cross-thread access" exception from WPF.

The file system watcher raises its events on a different thread and the dispatcher can be used to make that code run in the UI thread.

Use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke in that event handler and you'll be fine. :)